# angular 2 router hybrid app: url reverts back after navigate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-router

Every route change is rendering the correct component but has issue with path.
For example navigating from /items to /add-item changes and url for a second but then reverts it.
It happens on every page no matter from where to start and where to go.

Navigation

```
<a routerLink="/add-item">Add item</a>
```

Main app.routes.ts

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: 'brokers',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/'
},
{
    path: 'sellers',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/'
},
{
    path: 'buyers',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/'
},
{
    data: { name: 'pageNotFound' },
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/404'
}];
```

home.routes.ts

```
export const homeRoutes: Routes = [{
    component: HomePageComponent,
    data: { name: 'homePage' },
    path: ''
}
```

page-not-found.routes.ts

```
export const pageNotFoundRoutes: Routes = [{
    component: PageNotFoundComponent,
    data: { name: 'pageNotFound' },
    path: '404'
}]
```

add-item.routes.ts

```
export const addItemRoutes: Routes = [{
    component: AddItemComponent,
    data: { name: 'addItem' },
    path: 'add-item'
}]
```

items.routes.ts

```
export const itemsRoutes: Routes = [{
    component: ItemsComponent,
    data: { name: 'items' },
    path: 'items'
}];
```

All modules' routes are declared in import section like this

```
RouterModule.forChild(addItemRoutes)
```

Main routes

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: true })
```

Router tracing gives me no errors and correct urlAfterRedirects on NavigationEnd event.

Comment: Could you consider posting the lines of code before and after the declarations of your routes?

Comment: make sure you do not have empty strings in <a> tag while mentioning the routes!

Comment: @Edric It's just const and array brackets []

Comment: @alokstar It's like <a routerLink="/add-item">Add item</a>

Comment: @DzmitryVasilevsky routerLink shoud be like this [routerLink] ="/add-item"

Comment: can you try going to the path directly without any clicks to check if it holds the path?

Comment: @bikashdas Where did you get this stuff? You can use bindings to strings without brackets.  
https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links

Comment: @alokstar this.router.navigate(['/add-item']); - the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to anyone who will meet the same problem.
If you have hybrid AngularJS to Angular app you have to keep old $locationProvider settings like `$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });`
Otherwise your new Angular routing will meet this issue.

Or you can switch off Angular.js route manipulation with such a hack

```
$provide.decorator('$browser', ['$delegate', ($delegate) => {

    $delegate.onUrlChange = () => {};
    $delegate.url = () => {

        return '';

    };

    return $delegate;

}]);
```